# Error: Unique constraint failed on the fields: (id) when creating a field using Prisma in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

I'm encountering an issue while creating a field using Prisma in a Node.js application. I have a Field model defined as follows:

```
  model Field {
  id              String            @id @default(uuid())
  label           String
  type            FieldType // Enum for field types
  placeholder     String?
  isRequired      Boolean           @default(false)
  validations     FieldValidation[]
  defaultValue    String?
  size            Int?
  isDisabled      Boolean           @default(false)
  isReadOnly      Boolean           @default(false)
  helpText        String?
  styles          Json? // JSON object for CSS styles
  cssClass        String?
  customActions   Json? // JSON object for custom actions
  createdAt       DateTime          @default(now())
  updatedAt       DateTime          @updatedAt
  form            Form              @relation(fields: [id], references: [id])
  formId          String
  fieldOptions    FieldOption[]     @relation("FieldOptions")
  fieldAttributes FieldAttribute[] // Relationship with field attributes
}
```

When I attempt to create a new field using the following endpoint and payload:

Controller:

```
export const createField = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        const { formId, ...data } = req.body;
        const newField = await FieldModel.createField({
            ...data,
            formId,
            form: { connect: { id: formId } },
        });
        res.status(201).json(newField);
    } catch (error: unknown) {
        if (error instanceof Error) {
            res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
        } else {
            res.status(500).json({ error: "An unexpected error occurred" });
        }
    }
}
```

Payload sent via Postman:

```
{
  "label": "Example Field",
  "type": "TEXT",
  "placeholder": "Enter text here",
  "isRequired": false,
  "defaultValue": "Default value",
  "size": 10,
  "isDisabled": false,
  "isReadOnly": false,
  "helpText": "Helpful text",
  "styles": null,
  "cssClass": "example-field",
  "formId":"0eff7b48-6993-4762-86b5-51ae5f7b4edf"
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
"error": "Invalid `prisma.field.create()` invocation... Unique constraint failed on the fields: (`id`)"
```

It seems like the id field, marked as @id @default(uuid()) in the model, is conflicting when attempting to create the new field, and somehow the formId is being used as the id during creation.

How can I resolve this issue to successfully create a new field without encountering this unique constraint error?

**Additionally, I noticed that for some reason, when creating the Field model, it is using the same ID as the formId. This seems to be causing conflicts with the unique ID constraint.**

I've attempted to modify the controller logic by removing the id field from the creation data, but the problem persists. Any insights or suggestions on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that sticks out is that using both `formId: xx` and `form: { connect: { id: formId } }` is redundant. You should be able to use only the short form `formId: xx` as described [in the documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#connect). So the code would be:

```js
const newField = await FieldModel.create({
  ...data,
  formId,
});
```

A question: why does your example say `FieldModel.createField` instead of `.create`? Are you using some kind of custom abstraction layer instead of calling Prisma client directly; could that be causing issues?